# Troubleshooting a NotReady node

Tags: kubernetes

I have one node that is giving me some trouble at the moment. Not found a solution as of yet but that might be a skill level problem, Google coming up empty, or I have found some unsolvable issue. The latter is highly unlikely.

```
kubectl version v1.8.5
docker version 1.12.6
```

Doing some normal maintenance on my nodes I noticed the following:

```
NAME                            STATUS   ROLES     AGE       VERSION
ip-192-168-4-14.ourdomain.pro   Ready    master    213d      v1.8.5
ip-192-168-4-143.ourdomain.pro  Ready    master    213d      v1.8.5
ip-192-168-4-174.ourdomain.pro  Ready    <none>    213d      v1.8.5
ip-192-168-4-182.ourdomain.pro  Ready    <none>    46d       v1.8.5
ip-192-168-4-221.ourdomain.pro  Ready    <none>    213d      v1.8.5
ip-192-168-4-249.ourdomain.pro  Ready    master    213d      v1.8.5
ip-192-168-4-251.ourdomain.pro  NotReady <none>    206d      v1.8.5
```

On the **NotReady** node, I am unable to **attach** or **exec** myself in which seems normal when in a **NotReady** state unless I am misreading it. Not able to look at any specific logs on that node for the same reason.

At this point, I restarted **kubelet** and attached myself to the logs simultaneously to see if anything out of the ordinary would appear.

I have attached the things I spent a day Googling but I can not confirm is the actually connected to the problem.

**ERROR 1**

```
unable to connect to Rkt api service
```

We are not using this so I put this on the ignore list.

**ERROR 2**

```
unable to connect to CRI-O api service
```

We are not using this so I put this on the ignore list.

**ERROR 3**

```
Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data for container /
```

I have not been able to exclude this as potential pitfall but the things I have found thus far do not seem to relate to the version I am running.

**ERROR 4**

```
skipping pod synchronization - [container runtime is down PLEG is not healthy
```

I do not have an answer for this one except for the fact that the garbage collection error above appears a second time after this message.

**ERROR 5**

```
Registration of the rkt container factory failed
```

Not using this so it should fail unless I am mistaken.

**ERROR 6**

```
Registration of the crio container factory failed
```

Not using this so it should fail unless, again, I am mistaken.

**ERROR 7**

```
28087 docker_sandbox.go:343] failed to read pod IP from plugin/docker: NetworkPlugin cni failed on the status hook for pod "kube-dns-545bc4bfd4-rt7qp_kube-system": CNI failed to retrieve network namespace path: Cannot find network namespace for the terminated container
```

Found a Github ticket for this one but seems it's fixed so not sure how it relates.

**ERROR 8**

```
28087 kubelet_node_status.go:791] Node became not ready: {Type:Ready Status:False LastHeartbeatTime:2019-05-06 05:00:40.664331773 +0000 UTC LastTransitionTime:2019-05-06 05:00:40.664331773 +0000 UTC Reason:KubeletNotReady Message:container runtime is down}
```

And here the node goes into NotReady.

**Last log messages and status**

```
    systemctl status kubelet
  kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-05-06 05:00:39 UTC; 1h 58min ago
     Docs: http://kubernetes.io/docs/
 Main PID: 28087 (kubelet)
    Tasks: 21
   Memory: 42.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           └─28087 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manife...
May 06 05:00:45 kube-master-1 kubelet[28087]: I0506 05:00:45.310305   28087 reconciler.go:212] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for vo...4a414b9c")
May 06 05:00:45 kube-master-1 kubelet[28087]: I0506 05:00:45.310330   28087 reconciler.go:212] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for vo...4a414b9c")
May 06 05:00:45 kube-master-1 kubelet[28087]: I0506 05:00:45.310359   28087 reconciler.go:212] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "varl...
May 06 05:00:45 kube-master-1 kubelet[28087]: I0506 05:00:45.310385   28087 reconciler.go:212] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "cali...
May 06 05:00:45 kube-master-1 kubelet[28087]: I0506 05:00:45.310408   28087 reconciler.go:212] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "kube...
May 06 05:00:45 kube-master-1 kubelet[28087]: I0506 05:00:45.310435   28087 reconciler.go:212] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for vo...4a414b9c")
May 06 05:00:45 kube-master-1 kubelet[28087]: I0506 05:00:45.310456   28087 reconciler.go:212] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for vo...4a414b9c")
May 06 05:00:45 kube-master-1 kubelet[28087]: I0506 05:00:45.310480   28087 reconciler.go:212] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "ca-c...
May 06 05:00:45 kube-master-1 kubelet[28087]: I0506 05:00:45.310504   28087 reconciler.go:212] operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume "k8s-...
May 06 05:14:29 kube-master-1 kubelet[28087]: E0506 05:14:29.848530   28087 helpers.go:468] PercpuUsage had 0 cpus, but the actual number is 2; ignoring extra CPUs
```

Here is the **kubectl get po -o wide** output.

```
NAME                                              READY     STATUS     RESTARTS   AGE       IP               NODE
docker-image-prune-fhjkl                          1/1       Running    4          213d      100.96.67.87     ip-192-168-4-249
docker-image-prune-ltfpf                          1/1       Running    4          213d      100.96.152.74    ip-192-168-4-143
docker-image-prune-nmg29                          1/1       Running    3          213d      100.96.22.236    ip-192-168-4-221
docker-image-prune-pdw5h                          1/1       Running    7          213d      100.96.90.116    ip-192-168-4-174
docker-image-prune-swbhc                          1/1       Running    0          46d       100.96.191.129   ip-192-168-4-182
docker-image-prune-vtsr4                          1/1       NodeLost   1          206d      100.96.182.197   ip-192-168-4-251
fluentd-es-4bgdz                                  1/1       Running    6          213d      192.168.4.249    ip-192-168-4-249
fluentd-es-fb4gw                                  1/1       Running    7          213d      192.168.4.14     ip-192-168-4-14
fluentd-es-fs8gp                                  1/1       Running    6          213d      192.168.4.143    ip-192-168-4-143
fluentd-es-k572w                                  1/1       Running    0          46d       192.168.4.182    ip-192-168-4-182
fluentd-es-lpxhn                                  1/1       Running    5          213d      192.168.4.174    ip-192-168-4-174
fluentd-es-pjp9w                                  1/1       Unknown    2          206d      192.168.4.251    ip-192-168-4-251
fluentd-es-wbwkp                                  1/1       Running    4          213d      192.168.4.221    ip-192-168-4-221
grafana-76c7dbb678-p8hzb                          1/1       Running    3          213d      100.96.90.115    ip-192-168-4-174
model-5bbe4862e4b0aa4f77d0d499-7cb4f74648-g8xmp   2/2       Running    2          101d      100.96.22.234    ip-192-168-4-221
model-5bbe4862e4b0aa4f77d0d499-7cb4f74648-tvp4m   2/2       Running    2          101d      100.96.22.235    ip-192-168-4-221
prometheus-65b4b68d97-82vr7                       1/1       Running    3          213d      100.96.90.87     ip-192-168-4-174
pushgateway-79f575d754-75l6r                      1/1       Running    3          213d      100.96.90.83     ip-192-168-4-174
rabbitmq-cluster-58db9b6978-g6ssb                 2/2       Running    4          181d      100.96.90.117    ip-192-168-4-174
replicator-56x7v                                  1/1       Running    3          213d      100.96.90.84     ip-192-168-4-174
traefik-ingress-6dc9779596-6ghwv                  1/1       Running    3          213d      100.96.90.85     ip-192-168-4-174
traefik-ingress-6dc9779596-ckzbk                  1/1       Running    4          213d      100.96.152.73    ip-192-168-4-143
traefik-ingress-6dc9779596-sbt4n                  1/1       Running    3          213d      100.96.22.232    ip-192-168-4-221
```

Output of **kubectl get po -n kube-system -o wide**

```
NAME                                       READY     STATUS     RESTARTS   AGE       IP          
calico-kube-controllers-78f554c7bb-s7tmj   1/1       Running    4          213d      192.168.4.14
calico-node-5cgc6                          2/2       Running    9          213d      192.168.4.249
calico-node-bbwtm                          2/2       Running    8          213d      192.168.4.14
calico-node-clwqk                          2/2       NodeLost   4          206d      192.168.4.251
calico-node-d2zqz                          2/2       Running    0          46d       192.168.4.182
calico-node-m4x2t                          2/2       Running    6          213d      192.168.4.221
calico-node-m8xwk                          2/2       Running    9          213d      192.168.4.143
calico-node-q7r7g                          2/2       Running    8          213d      192.168.4.174
cluster-autoscaler-65d6d7f544-dpbfk        1/1       Running    10         207d      100.96.67.88
kube-apiserver-ip-192-168-4-14             1/1       Running    6          213d      192.168.4.14
kube-apiserver-ip-192-168-4-143            1/1       Running    6          213d      192.168.4.143
kube-apiserver-ip-192-168-4-249            1/1       Running    6          213d      192.168.4.249
kube-controller-manager-ip-192-168-4-14    1/1       Running    5          213d      192.168.4.14
kube-controller-manager-ip-192-168-4-143   1/1       Running    6          213d      192.168.4.143
kube-controller-manager-ip-192-168-4-249   1/1       Running    6          213d      192.168.4.249
kube-dns-545bc4bfd4-rt7qp                  3/3       Running    13         213d      100.96.19.197
kube-proxy-2bn42                           1/1       Running    0          46d       192.168.4.182
kube-proxy-95cvh                           1/1       Running    4          213d      192.168.4.174
kube-proxy-bqrhw                           1/1       NodeLost   2          206d      192.168.4.251
kube-proxy-cqh67                           1/1       Running    6          213d      192.168.4.14
kube-proxy-fbdvx                           1/1       Running    4          213d      192.168.4.221
kube-proxy-gcjxg                           1/1       Running    5          213d      192.168.4.249
kube-proxy-mt62x                           1/1       Running    4          213d      192.168.4.143
kube-scheduler-ip-192-168-4-14             1/1       Running    6          213d      192.168.4.14
kube-scheduler-ip-192-168-4-143            1/1       Running    6          213d      192.168.4.143
kube-scheduler-ip-192-168-4-249            1/1       Running    6          213d      192.168.4.249
kubernetes-dashboard-7c5d596d8c-q6sf2      1/1       Running    5          213d      100.96.22.230
tiller-deploy-6d9f596465-svpql             1/1       Running    3          213d      100.96.22.231
```

I am a bit lost at this point of where to go from here. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the kubelet must be down.

share the output from below command

```
journalctl -u kubelet
```

share the output from the below command

```
kubectl get po -n kube-system -owide
```

It appears like the node is not able to communicate with the control plane.
you can below steps

1. detached the node from cluster ( cordon the node, drain the node and finally delete the node)
2. reset the node
3. rejoin the node as fresh to cluster

Comment: Hi, 

Here is a tail of the log that comes with the systemctl command. Be happy to share the full log if you think that would be helpful but it will take some time to clean it up. Here I just wanted to show that kubelet is running but maybe you asked about something I did fully understand?

Appending the logs to my original message.

Comment: Appended the asked output to the original question

Comment: kubectl get po -n kube-system -owide

Comment: need core services status from kube-system namespace

Comment: Added the requested output.

Comment: Thank you. I am familiar with the steps mentioned in 1 but not in 2 and 3. Can you link to some documentation or elaborate?

Comment: how did you join the node to cluster?

Comment: No idea. Inherited this thing and just learning as I go. I did find a config file using kubeadm config view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192897/discussion-between-petter-and-p-ekambaram).